# PDF get PDF dimensions

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am working in PHP and want to get the dimensions of a pdf document so that I can find the orientation and append it to another PDF that is generated on the fly using mpdf. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed Dompdf or the Zend extension? They come with a whole lot of features - they might help you finding the dimensions.

dompdf: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
Zend PDF: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html